# How do I return data from a 'for' loop in Go?

Tags: for-loop, go

I'm trying to convert a `[]*Struct` to a JSON response. I'm able to get the data from the `[]*Struct` and iterate over it. The part I get stuck around is the iterating over a loop and then returning the data to an `interface{}`.

I've tried to putting an interface in an interface, but I just can't make ends meet. Here's what I have at the moment; I was told to turn to Stack Overflow if I had any issues.

```golang
package main

import (
   "log"
   "context"
   "cloud.google.com/go/datastore"
)

var ctx = context.Background()

type ItemList struct {
    Id    string    `datastore:"_id"`
    Name  string    `datastore:"name"`
}

type Data struct {
    ManyItems   []Item
}

type Item struct {
    Id    string    `json:"id"`
    Name  string    `json:"name"`
}

func Get() ([]*ItemList, error) {
  client, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, "project-name")
  if err != nil {
     log.Println(err)
  }

  var Response []*ItemList
  query := datastore.NewQuery("query")
  _, err = client.GetAll(ctx, query, &Response)
  if err != nil {
     log.Println(err)
  }

  return Response, error
}

func Read() (interface{}) {
   resp, err := Get()
   if err != nil {
      log.Println(err)
   }

   for i, _ := range resp {
     // this is where i get stuck
     r := &Data{
               ManyItems: Item{
                        Id: resp[i].Id,
                        Name: resp[i].Name,
               },
          }
     return r
   }
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Well, for one, your `Read()` doesn't have a return type.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning inside the for loop and this will only return the first item.

Also I see that ManyItems is an array of Item ([]Item) and you are assigning a single Item which is wrong.

**Update**:
Here you have the complete code:

```
// Input Json data
type ItemList struct {
    Id    string    `datastore:"_id"`
    Name  string    `datastore:"name"`
}

//Convert *ItemList to *Item
func (list *ItemList) ToItem() *Item {
    return &Item {
        Id    : list.Id,
        Name  : list.Name,
    }
}
```

```
// Output Json data
type Data struct {
    ManyItems   []*Item `json:"data"`
}

//Output json item object
type Item struct {
    Id    string    `json:"id"`
    Name  string    `json:"name"`
}
```

```
// The read function
func Read() (string, error) {
   resp, err := Get()
   if err != nil {
      log.Println(err)
      return "", err
   }

   list := make([]Item, len(resp))
   for i, _ := range resp {
     list[i] = resp[i].ToItem()
   }

    b, err := json.Marshal(&Data{list})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return "", err
    }

   return string(b), nil
}
```

Test: [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GMo1nCoN2R6)

Answer (score 2):

You can predeclare a `*Data` variable and then inside the loop, on each iteration add the item to its `ManyItems` field. Since `ItemList` and `Item` have the same structure, ie the same fields in the same order, you can convert directly one to the other. ([As long as you are on Go 1.8 or newer](https://golang.org/doc/go1.8#language))

```
func Read() interface{} {
    resp, err := Get()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil
    }

    data := &Data{ManyItems: make([]Item, len(resp))}
    for i := range resp {
        data.ManyItems[i] = Item(*resp[i])
    }
    return data
}
```

However if possible it would be more efficient to just return the slice you already have, something like this.

```
type ItemList struct {
    Id   string `datastore:"_id" json:"id"`
    Name string `datastore:"name" json:"name"`
}

type Data struct {
    ManyItems []*ItemList
}

func Read() interface{} {
    resp, err := Get()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil
    }

    return &Data{ManyItems: resp}
}
```